# how to the hide fragment switcher tabs allways

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

hello all I'm making an app and basicly i was wondering if i could hide these tabs for fragment switching [image] If you need any of my code pleas ask, there is tons just for the fragment and the tabs and im not sure what is looked at as beneficial thanks.

```
public class HomeMediaFragment extends Fragment implements
    ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

ListView list;

private ViewPager viewPager;
private MediaFragment mAdapter;

private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "The Time the School Almost (Actually) Burned Down", "The time the math exams were almost cancelled", "The Time NT almost didn't get a new School"," The time the old school almost fell down","The Time NT almost got a new pool","The Time We Almost Killed Graffiti","The Time the Exams Almost Got Destroyed","The Time we had a snow day","The Time The School Almost Fell Down", "+2" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media, container, false);



    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new MediaFragment(getChildFragmentManager());

    if(actionBar.getTabCount() > 0){
        actionBar.removeAllTabs();
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));


    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

    return v;
}




@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code that you use to set up the menu. It would likely be in the enclosing activity, not the fragment itself.

Comment: its quite lengthy but i added the hosting activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out these lines:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));


    }
```

and these:

```
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}
```

The first set of lines is setting your navigation mode to tabs, which isn't necessary if you're just switching fragments, and adding the tabs to the view. The second is just the listeners that get called from the .setTabListener in the first part.

Comment: the tabs are still there and they still work perfectly, anythoughts??

Comment: Try deleting "implements ActionBar.Tablistener" in your first line and "actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);" in your onPageSelected function.

Comment: "implements ActionBar.Tablistener" i already had removed to remove error "actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);" doesnt make tabs go away

Comment: Hm...I'm at a bit of a loss here, my last suggestion would be to put "actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);" where you used to have the NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS.